# Drag events does not fire

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, drag

I am trying to make a div list draggable. I tried using drag events however, when I debug, I realize that it even does not get into the functions. What may be the problem? Here is my code:

```
setDragDrop() {
    const cols = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
    [].forEach.call(cols, (col) => {
        col.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
        col.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            col.bool = false;
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            col.layer.dragSrcEl_ = col;
            col.classList.add('moving');
        }, true);
        col.addEventListener('dragenter', (e) => {
            col.classList.add('over');
        }, false);
        col.addEventListener('dragover', this.handleDragOver, false);
        col.addEventListener('dragleave', (e) => {
            col.classList.remove('over');
        }, false);
        col.addEventListener('drop', this.handleDrop, false);
        col.addEventListener('dragend', this.handleDragEnd, false);
    });

}
```

Comment: Before anything, using arrow function as event handler is a bad choice. Are you using `this` inside any handler?

Comment: I want to write as ES6 syntax

Comment: You want to write code in modern style that does not mean you have to use arrow function everywhere. People introduced it for a reason. If you use it without a thought, you'll endup wasting more time in fixing issue.

Comment: Also if I remember correctly arrow method and foreach does not supported in IE, so if you want cross browser support then do not use them.

Comment: Do you allow JQuery or only pure javascript?

Comment: I prefer pure javascript